# what happand to socket, when the other end close it?

Tags: c++, sockets, winapi, winsock2

I want to develop a client server app and I want to make it as robust as possible. There are multiple questions come up for me, and I just can't find an unambiguous answer on the internet.
Let's say, that the server is running on a while(TRUE) loop and check for command existance is it's commands queue, if there is one, it sends it, if there isn't one, it just continue to the head of the loop.
But what if the other end went down, or there is a connection error between the two, what happen to the socket value, does it become INVALID_SOCKET?

```
while (TRUE) {
       if (ReqQueue->size() != 0 && ReqQueue->front() != string("STOP")) { // there is some command in the ReqQueue which is NOT STOP.
           int sent = send(ClientSocket, ReqQueue->front().c_str(), (int)strlen(ReqQueue->front().c_str()), 0);
           if (sent == (int)strlen(ReqQueue->front().c_str()))
               ReqQueue->pop(); // Next Command.
           else if (int err = WSAGetLastError() == WSAETIMEDOUT){
                   shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_BOTH);
                   closesocket(ClientSocket);
                   return;
            }
        else 
            continue;
    }
    else if (ReqQueue->size() == 0) {
        continue;
    }
    else if(ReqQueue->front() == string("STOP"))
    {
        if (send(ClientSocket, "STOP", strlen("STOP"), 0) == strlen("STOP")) {
            /*Message received indication from target*/
            shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_BOTH);
            closesocket(ClientSocket);
            return;
        }
    }
}
shutdown(ClientSocket, SD_BOTH);
closesocket(ClientSocket);
return 0;
```

that's the source :)

what I want to ask is, there is a better way to implement the above goal, maybe I can change the while loop condition to something like while(the socket is OK) or while(there is still a connection).

Comment: If the other end of a (TCP) connection closes its socket, then your next `recv` call will return `0` indicating the closing. Trying to continue to use the socket will lead to errors.

Comment: Just triggered by *"and I want to make it as robust as possible"*; have you considered to apply a high-level protocol such as http? There are ton's of (tested) libraries which implement's that kind of stuff.

Comment: On an unrelated note, [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) have [`operator==` overloads](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_cmp) that take pointers to constant strings (like a string literal). That means you don't need `string("STOP")` for comparison. Doing e.g. `ReqQueue->front() == "STOP"` should work just as fine.

Comment: "Is there a better way" since you're on windows; look up `select` (Linux has a better version called `poll`; but it's very buggy on windows and is not recommended for use; even by microsoft)

Comment: as you can see, there is no recv call in the above code, I want to be noticed without recv @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: You should drop blocking IO and switch to overlapped / asynchronous calls. Create socket with `WSA_FLAG_OVERLAPPED` flag and use corresponding overlapped calls. See [overlapped socket](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2B%2B%5D+overlapped+socket)

Comment: I tried select, but really didn't go well.. @UKMonkey

Comment: @LAvR well, you asked if there was a better way and that's it ;)  I'd suggest you go back to trying that and then post a question when you get stuck

Comment: You can't. It's part of the TCP specification. If  the other end of the connection is nicely closed then the socket on your end becomes readable and the next receive operation will return `0` bytes received. A framework may abstract this for you into events or something, but the underlying mechanism can't really change.

Comment: what if the connection was not nicely closed, what can I do about it ? @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: should I use select on both ends the client and the server? @UKMonkey

Comment: @LAvR I would personally suggest you make a library for it - then you only read/write a socket in a single way; but the impact on the server is much more significant than on the client.

Comment: If there was an "error" in any way, then the next transmit function (`recv` or `send`) will return with an error. What you can do depends on the error, but in most cases it's not recoverable and you should close your end.

Comment: thank you ;) @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: what is the meanning of give a NULL time out to the select ? @UKMonkey

Comment: @LAvR Have you considered looking up anything you've been told here? It's all documented.

Comment: @LAvR What do you think it means?  (research is hard and slow - and you'll find that software engineers have to do it ALL THE TIME) For that reason I don't want to spoon feed you; but have you tell me what you think it means, and why...  and then I shouldn't have to reply, because you'll have convinced yourself that you're right :)

Answer (score 1):

> what happen to the socket value

Nothing. A `send()` on that socket will eventually fail, and a `recv()` on it will deliver zero or -1, but the socket itself remains open, and the variable value is unaffected. There is no magic.

> does it become INVALID_SOCKET?

No.

Answer (score 0):

For me, better idea would be when you receive a request to your server from any client, just create a new thread and assign the task to that thread. By doing that you can make your server parallel processing of client request and work on multiple request from multiple client. Hence no client need to wait for server to complete the request of a client already submitted a request. If you implement like this you don’t need to bother what will happened if a connection broken. In normal case if a correction broken you will get this information in your server while sending the reply to the client and you can mark that process as failed and log it into server log.

Comment: *just create a new thread* - bad idea. need use asynchronous processing instead this

Comment: As child thread will be created based on every client request and that newly created thread will do all the work and send the request back to the client from itself load on main thread will be minimal. How do you design a server to process hundreds of client request parallels? Suppose a server need 1 minutes to process a request from a client. IF 100 clients tries to connect to the server at the same time in that scenario what will happened to 100th clinet. It has to wait for 100 minutes. Creating child thread based on request will work almost like asynchronously.

Comment: threads count must be equal core count not more. and i always write asynchronous servers.need not  *almost like asynchronously* but exactly asynchronous for good perfomance and low resource as possible

Comment: Agree. You need to control the thread based on number of processor in the server. You need to follow FIFO  scheduling.

Comment: really we simply pop packets from queue (iocp). iocp of course fifo